# HereMap for China Js lib does not work as servers not deployed?

Tags: here-api

We know the China Here is in Beta version, and we tested some REST api by reading your documentation here: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation?variant=cn, and they are working such as geocode, routing rest api.

However when we try to use the interactive map (js lib), we found out the js lib can not be used,
we are including this js header provide by Here documentation :

```html
<script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

We found out that the js is trying to connecting to your CN maptiles servers, but they are 
not availabe, those servers are like :
https://1.base.maps.cit.hereapi.cn/maptile
https://route.cit.hereapi.cn

Comment: Can you please share some more error or code snippets so that we can better understand, APIs are running fine though, no such issue reported from other customers

Answer (score 0):

Js library should work as per the documentation please try to use the code as below-

```
<html>


 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
  <script>
    // Initialize the platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE}'
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```